# Xamarin Forms event of after install

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'd like to trigger some code to happen after the user installs a version of our Xamarin Forms application.  But I need it for every version install, not just the first installation, so setting a property flag won't work.

I have a solution that tracks application version numbers and can trigger it off that, but I was hoping there was an framework event or something that was more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Xamarin Essentials' [Version Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/version-tracking)

From there you can check when either the first time the current build is run, or the first time the current version is run:

```cs
// First time launching current version
var firstLaunchCurrent = VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchForCurrentVersion;

// First time launching current build
var firstLaunchBuild = VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchForCurrentBuild;
```